# I need to plot some 2d data through time (thus 3d)

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have an xts object of data through time:

```
> head(vixData[,2:8], 5)
              F1    F2    F3    F4    F5    F6    F7
2009-06-08 30.25 32.00 31.70 31.75 31.65 30.85 29.95
2009-06-09 29.10 30.95 30.95 31.15 31.10 30.40 29.45
2009-06-10 29.10 31.20 31.30 31.45 31.50 30.75 29.95
2009-06-11 28.10 30.60 30.75 30.90 31.00 30.20 29.25
2009-06-12 28.35 29.95 30.10 30.45 30.50 29.90 29.05
```

The F1-F7 will form a curve, like below:

```
plot(1:7, vixData[399,2:8], type = 'o', pch = 6)
```

[image]

I would like to do this through time. The rows of the xts object are the values for each day, which generate the curve. I am looking to generate something like this:

[image]

I am trying to use plot3D, and surf3D, but I cannot understand the documentation, or how to convert the dataframe into what surf3D wants. Any ideas or better package suggestions?

I have tried to use lattice::wireframe as suggested in the comments, but I get the following:

```
curveData <- vixData[-(1:100),2:8, drop = FALSE]
wireframe(t(as.matrix(curveData)), shade = TRUE, scales = list(arrows = FALSE),
      aspect = c(0.65, 0.25), drape = TRUE, 
      zlab = "Level", xlab = "Contract", ylab = "Time", panel.aspect = .75)
```

[image]

This looks pretty close!! But - I am hoping I could maybe rotate the image and extend it some along the 'Time' axis, to give better clarity. Are there parameters for that? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: What exactly did you try and what didn't work? Seem like just converting to matrix would work with wireframe: `lattice::wireframe(as.matrix(vixData), drape=TRUE)`

Comment: I was trying to use plot3D. I will try lattice, I had not heard of it.

Comment: You could also plot on a flat (2D) graph with Date on the x axis and F1:7 on the y axis with colour used to represent your values. You'll need to convert your data to a matrix and can then use image().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source file of chartSeries3d should help. Also, you may be interested in the

```
source("http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/chartSeries3d.alpha.R")
library("xts")
data("sample_matrix")
chartSeries3d0( as.xts( sample_matrix ), col=c("lightblue","blue"))
```

[image: TimeSeriesPlot]

Answer (score -1):

Excel 3D surface chart is best option for you.
even Excel 2007 has that chart.
you can rotate axis, change colors easily

[click volcano data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJQWJ.png)

Comment: No. This is R. Get out with that Excel nonsense.